# How to move specific client div his mouse position for all the other clients

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sockets, socket.io

I have build the project using socket.io, I create it for every connected user a div (with his sessionID) and every mouse click move his div to the click position in his web and to all others the sockets. but I have a problem, when user Clicks on the screen - it move the div to his position but to all other clients it move to **their** last click position.

Here`s what I have done:

```js
socket.on('addPlayer', function(user) {
    $('#stage').append('<div class="player" id="user_' + user + '">' + user +'</div>');
});

$('#stage').on('click', function(e) {
 
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;  

    xp += (mouseX - xp);
    yp += (mouseY - yp);

    socket.emit('move', {
        xp: xp,
        yp: yp
    });
});

socket.on('move', function(data) {
 $('#user_' + data).animate({ left: xp + 'px', top: yp + 'px' }, 400 );
});
```

**My server side**

```js
socket.on('move', function(data) {
    io.emit('move', socket.id);
});
```

Anyone see the problem? Please help me on this regards..

Comment: seems like you are setting the let and top using global `xp` and `yp` not on what you pass into `data`

Comment: when you `.emit('move')` you pass `xp` and `yp` to the server, but when you receive in `.on('emit')` the server does not send you any `xp` and `yp`.

Comment: @robinvrd I dont understand what to do. what I change to data.xp its dont move the div. without errors

Comment: @Dasmond show your `socket.emit('move')` on **server side**.

Comment: @robinvrd see edit

Comment: You are receiving `data` with `xp` and `yp` on your server but you are sending only `socket.id` to the others clients. You have to send `xp` and `yp` in `io.emit()` too.

Comment: @Dasmond my answer below should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the position using the data passed in. In your example, it is using a global `xp` and `yp`.

You have also not passed the `user` in with the data when you call `emit` so the other clients have no idea really which user should be moved. I would suggest also adding that as a field in the data you send.

```
socket.emit('move', {
        user: //THE VAR WHICH HOLDS THE SESSIONID FOR THIS USER
        xp: xp,
        yp: yp
    });
```

```
socket.on('move', function(data) {
    $('#user_' + data.user).animate({ left: data.xp + 'px', top: data.yp + 'px' }, 400 );
});
```

Comment: what is the structure of `data` in `socket.on` callback

Answer (score 0):

You should update the data you send through `move`.

You should have on server side something like :

```
socket.on('move', function(socket, data) {
    // broadcast to all sockets WHO is moving and WHERE
    io.emit('move', {userid: socket.id, xp: data.xp, yp: data.yp});
});
```

And on the client side something like :

```
$('#stage').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#my_user').animate({ left: e.pageX + "px", top: e.pageY + "px"  });

    socket.emit('move', {xp: e.pageX, yp: e.pageY});
});

socket.on('move', function(data) {
    // check if it is not your own informations that server send back to you
    if (data.userid != my_userid) {
        $('#user_' + data.userid).animate({ left: data.xp + "px", top: data.yp + "px"  });
    }
});
```